# Wordpress auto logout and page refresh

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a page that will automatically logout a user as soon as they land on it, then the page will immediately refresh. Once page reloads, the user will be signed out.  A similar behaviour is if the user opens the page in Incognito except I want this to happen automatically when they open a link to this page.

I only want this to occur in select pages, I thought a shortcode could be employed to execute the above but can't get it to work.

I have tried this hook, and then creating a shortcode as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26870082/log-out-wordpress-and-redirect-to-different-url) except I added the `get_permalink` function

```
add_action( 'wp_logout', 'redirect_after_logout');
function redirect_after_logout(){
  wp_redirect( get_permalink() );
  exit();
}

/* Add shortcode */
add_shortcode('logout_and_refresh', 'redirect_after_logout');
```

but it seems to need to be executed through the logout URL and I want it to happen automatically when the page loads.

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( 'http://redirect-url' ); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call `wp_logout()` function directly after `init` / `template_redirect` hooks.

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.7/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L618

But if you want to execute when document loaded, you could use javascript to redirect to your logout url.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var uri = <?php echo json_encode(wp_logout_url( 'http://redirect-url' ));?>;
    location.href = uri;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `init` action hook for that. first, you need to check is user logged or not. check below code. code will go in active theme function.php file. tested and works.

```
add_action( 'init', 'logout_user_land_on_page' );
function logout_user_land_on_page(){
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect( wp_login_url() );
        wp_logout();
        exit;   
    }
}
```